# Which arch shall I specify for Intel Threading Building

Tags: architecture, intel, tbb

I ran into O'Reilly's new book on TBB in bookstore today. Really liked how TBB abstract the threads into tasks. But I noticed that the tutorial, in page #12 install on Linux* systems, there are only three available s: ia32, intel64 and ia64.  Dmesg on our server shows this: `[    0.132804] CPU0: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q9400  @ 2.66GHz stepping 0a`.  Wondering which  shall I choose?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Please post the output from "`uname -a`" -- that'll give us information about how the OS is compiled.

Comment: Linux ... 2.6.31-22-server #60-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 2):

`ia32` is the classic 32-bit Intel ISA

`intel64` is 64-bit ISA originally developed by AMD.

`ia64` is Itanium

For your machine its `intel64`.